# Does vim.less work on windows?

Tags: vim, window

Vim comes with a script that is supposed to make it behave like an advanced version of less.

As per [this blog article](http://wazem.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-use-script-highlight-on-less-vim.html), one can use vim as a pager by setting up this alias:

```
alias lessv='/usr/share/vim/vim71/macros/less.sh'
```

However, if I do this on windows:

```
type console.aspx |vim -u "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\macros\less.vim"
```

Vim just kind of hangs there and does not respond to keystrokes. I have to kill the vim process to get my command line back. Is there a way to make this work on windows?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a DOS batch file equivalent of macros\less.sh. The macros\less.vim file is just a set of macros that remap keys to make Vim behave more like less; macros\less.vim has to be read by Vim, not executed by itself.

I don't know enough about batch file programming to give you a complete solution, but this much will handle the case of reading the output of a pipe:

```
"C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\vim.exe" --cmd "let no_plugin_maps = 1" -c "runtime! macros/less.vim" -
```

Put that line into a file named less.bat. You may have to change the path to vim.exe for your installation, or replace it with just `vim.exe` if vim.exe is in your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you people from the year 2011 have this yet, but those of us in year 2023 have a convenient file named `less.bat` that's located in the same directory as the `less.vim` file.

So I recommend looking in your `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\macros\` directory to see if the `less.bat` file exists there.  If it does, just add that directory to your `PATH` (the environment variable), and you can use the `less` command just as you would in most any Unix system:

```
less file.txt
some_command_with_output.exe | less
```

Of course, now that it's 2023 (or later, if you're from the future), you may want upgrade -- if you haven't already -- to a newer version of `vim`.  Then you'll almost certainly get `less.bat`, even if you're not on a Windows platform.  (Just be aware that the path will most certainly be different, as the `macros` folder for Vim 8 won't be found under `Vim\vim73`.)

Have fun with it!